# Reading last modified time from a file in php

Tags: php, twitter, web

I can feed the tweet in my web page using Twitter API and everything works fine. But here is something different I want to do and having quite hard time:
I have a text file that has to be updated with the tweet feed using twitter API every hour. And all the tweet data will get stored in that text file. 
My web site shall access to the text file and update the tweet data.
Every time web site access the text file last modified time, web site shall check the last modified date for that text file. If the date is older than an hour, it should update itself with the data from the file else stay as it is. 
I have the following PHP function to read the last modified time:

```
$filename = 'textfile.txt';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "$filename was last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename));
}
```

I also have a tweeter API working that feeds directly from twitter. But to make the site working faster, I want to twist the way. 
Anybody?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I m sorry if I m not clear, I question is: I want to update my text file with the twitter API feed so that my web page can extract the tweet feed from the text file in an span of an hour checking the last modified time instead of accessing the twitter server every time page loads in.

Comment: That's still not a question, that's just describing your goal. What problem are you having doing it? Show the code you've written that tries to do it, and explain what's going wrong.

Comment: compare the filemtime with the current time. If file doesnt exist or is older than an hour download and store the file from twitter. If not, use the file. The keyword you are looking for is "Caching".

Answer (score -1):

From the PHP manuall

> Note: The results of this function are cached. See [clearstatcache()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) for more details.